# Exporting DataGridView to Excel with Interop causes Outlook 2010 to crash

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, excel-interop

I have a Windows Form Application with DataGridViews, on two of these grids I have an Export button that allows the user to export the data in the grid to an excel file.

The export appears to be working perfectly, the EXCEL.EXE process is ended correctly after the event has executed and the excel file that gets created is perfect. But after exporting one of my datagridviews to excel, if I try to send a new email or reply to an email in Outlook 2010, Outlook will stop working.

After a few tries I get the "Outlook has experience a serious problem with the 'microsoft outlook social connector' add-in..." error
[image]

I'm positive that it's my export function in my app that causes this because Outlook behaves fine *until* I export, immediately after it will crash if I try to send an email. I can duplicate this at will and I've also duplicated this result on other workstations.

My Outlook and the Outlook on the other workstations that experienced this, all have a custom add-in. This add-in uses the following namespaces:

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using RibbonStuff = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Here is the code from my export event.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void exportUpdateGridToExcel()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = null;
    Excel.Workbook xlBook = null;
    Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = null;
    try
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "Inventory_Adjustment_Export.xls";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Copy DataGridView results to clipboard
            copyAlltoClipboard(dgvItems);

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false; // Without this you will get two confirm overwrite prompts
            xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            // Format column D as text
            Excel.Range rng = xlSheet.get_Range("D:D").Cells;
            rng.NumberFormat = "@";

            // Paste clipboard results to worksheet range
            Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            CR.Select();
            xlSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);

            // Delete blank row header column and select cell A1
            Excel.Range delRng = xlSheet.get_Range("A:A").Cells;
            delRng.Delete(Type.Missing);
            xlSheet.get_Range("A1").Select();

            // Save excel file and capture the location from the SaveFileDialog
            xlBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            // Clear Clipboard and select "Item" cell
            Clipboard.Clear();
            dgvItems.ClearSelection();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        xlBook.Close(false);
        xlApp.Quit();
    }
}

private void copyAlltoClipboard(DataGridView dv)
{
    dv.SelectAll();
    DataObject dataObj = dv.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
}
```

Comment: i executed the export grid a couple times, sent, replied emails and it did not crash my outlook.